# What is a neuron in large language models?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer, chatgpt, gpt, artificial-neuron

I'm reading OpenAI's new paper "[Language models can explain neurons in language models](https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/neuron-explainer/paper/index.html)" And I can't fully understand the concept of neurons here.

Can you please explain it? Is it related to the attention mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in this paper neuron means the perceptrons in the MLP layers of the transformer.